# Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.GridViewPager"

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-support-library

I'm trying to put together a wearable app and I keep encountering the error Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.GridViewPager". I'm also using android studio 1.0, and I can't find where to add a java build path. Here's what I have:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.1.71'
compile files('libs/support-v4-20.0.0-javadoc.jar')
}
```

[image]

[image]

I've looked around at a lot of problems similar to this, and most involve the support library. I have the support library installed and in my libs folder in the wear portion of my app, and I still get this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: "I can't find where to add a java build path" -- that is because you don't "add a java build path" in Eclipse (for Android development) *or* Android Studio. That goes double for most of the Android Support package, which is mostly AARs, not JARs. I see the `GridViewPager` class in `com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0` when I examine the AAR's contents. Where specifically in the IDE are you encountering this error?

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the wearable. The error comes up when it tried to run the module. I've been going off some open source code, so if they used a different support library I might have missed it. I'm still very new at this so I wouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use GridViewpager for wear you probably need

`android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager` not `android.support.v4.view.GridViewPager`